# Moving log4j.properties out of jar causing log4j warnings (logs are not generated)

Tags: java, shell, log4j, classloader

I have a shell script **test.sh** with following contents :

```
echo " Running test.sh ..." | log

test_cp=./test/jar/*:./test/lib/*
test_main=com.test.TestApp

java -cp $test_cp $test_main | log
```

The relative paths used in the above file are correct as far as I understand. In this case, **log4j jar** is located at **./test/lib/** and the **jar containing TestApp (test-app.jar)** is located at **./test/jar/**.

Now, the current scenario is that **log4j.properties** is packaged inside **test-app.jar** and all Java classes are using the log4j logger to create logs. The contents of log4j.properties are as follows :

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, CONSOLE, FILE


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %c %M - %n%m%n


log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=test-app.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %c %M - %n%m%n
```

We want to externalize the log4j.properties and move it outside the test-app.jar. For this, I have placed log4j.properties at ./test/properties/ and modified the shell script accordingly as follows :

```
echo " Running test.sh ..." | log

test_cp=./test/properties/*:./test/jar/*:./test/lib/*
test_main=com.test.TestApp

java -cp $test_cp $test_main | log
```

But I am getting the following error and no log file is generated, nor any logs get pronted on console.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.noknok.util.PropertiesLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I also read somewhere on the Internet that this could be a Java classloader issue, so I have tried changing the sequence of different locations in classpath, placing log4j.properties in the directories that are already included in the classpath, etc.

But I am still getting the same error.

Thanks a lot for the help! Please get back if you need any other info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure log4j picks the correct log4j.properties file by using `-Dlog4.debug`

You can specify the config file by `-Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/file`